# Improving code to increase performance of onClick, db update, and page reload activity

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, onclick

I've been using the code below to pass variables to another site, update a database, then refresh the body of the page to show the last item clicked. It has been working but I find that it's intermittantly unresponsive, or fails to complete. I'm wondering if anything can be done with the code below to make it react quicker and smoother. I guess it feels sloppy to me - but since I'm not a developer, it's hard to improve.

**ONCLICK URL CODE**

```
<script>
    var xmlHttp = null;

    function fetch(URL) {
        var today = new Date;
        var sURL = URL + '&time=' + today.getTime();
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", sURL, true );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE db & REFRESH BODY of PAGE**

```
<script>
    function updateArea1(el) {
      $.post("includes/db_updatePreQ1.php", {name: el.name} );
  $.ajax({
  url: "",
      context: document.body,
  success: function(s,x){
      $(this).html(s);
      }
  });
    }
</script>
```

**DB QUERY & VAR CREATION**

```
<?php
include 'includes/db_connect.php';
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM previewState WHERE area = 'preQ1'");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $preQ1 = ($row1['selected']);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**EXAMPLE OF BODY CODE**

```
<div class="controlArea">
<div id="sec1">
    <div id="secbuttons">
        <div id="fs1a">
            <a name="fs1" class="button" <?php if ( $preQ1 == 'fs1' ) echo "id='fs1b'" ?> onClick="fetch('http://10.10.10.20:88/?button=FS1'); updateArea1(this);"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="qv1a">
            <a name="qv1" class="button" <?php if ( $preQ1 == 'qv1' ) echo "id='qv1b'" ?>  onClick="fetch('http://10.10.10.20:88/?button=QV1'); updateArea1(this);"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hsa"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen if the "trouble" can be related to the destination side? Maybe it has problems.

Comment: I have @Goikiu - It's not the fastest server in the world but it should be able to handle all of this without a problem. My suspicion is that the problematic code is in the "onClick" fetch function. Maybe if this was reworked into JQuery code or similar?

Comment: I think that the fetch function is slow but i do not think there are other solutions.

Comment: I think I've actually worked out that the refresh part of the code is the one that intermittently fails. Is it likely there can be anything done to improve its functionality?